# Error LGHT0094 when making MSI from WIX : Unresolved reference to symbol

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, heat

Our product was using the visual studio 2008(.NET CLR Version v2.0.50727) for build and was using wix toolset 3.0.5210 to create the installer for our product.I recently upgraded to visual studio 2015(.NET CLR Version v4.0.30319) for building our product. After Building, im using the same WixToolset(3.0.5210) to create the installer, but i see the below error thrown from light.exe

> MakeMSIFromWIX Install\Product\NTX86\Product\release\Product\Product.msi T:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\bin_EnvironmentWizard.wxs(6) : error LGHT0130 : The primary key 'reg76DDE9DE58652D7858F9E6690F309CC8' is duplicated in table 'Registry'.  Please remove one of the entries or
>   rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.

I found this information "The collision appears to occur when there is a default value for the key. Removing the default value resolves the error". It was said that this could be a bug in the heat tool.
link : https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/747/

So i upgraded the wixtoolset and tried creating the installer, but i see the strange link errors.

```js
MakeMSIFromWIX Install\Product\NTX86\Product\release\Product\Product.msi
E:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\group_Client.wxs(12) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Comp.SystemFolder.AddFlow4.ocx' in section 'Fragment:Frag.Client'.
E:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\group_Client.wxs(13) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Comp.SystemFolder.HFlow.ocx' in section 'Fragment:Frag.Client'.
E:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\group_Client.wxs(19) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Comp.SystemFolder.msstkprp.dll' in section 'Fragment:Frag.Client'.
E:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\group_Client.wxs(148) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Comp.Bin.DXFC_net.dll' in section 'Fragment:Frag.Client'.
E:\Build\Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\group_Client.wxs(150) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Comp.Bin.ValNet.dll' in section 'Fragment:Frag.Client'.
E:\External\Wix\light.exe -nologo -spdb -sice:ICE03 -sice:ICE61 -ext E:\External\Wix\WixUtilExtension.dll -b Install\Product -out Install\Product\NTX86\Product\release\Product\Product.msi Install\Product\NTX86\Product\release\Product.wixobj Install\Wix\NTX86\Product\obj\Product.wix
```

I see this link errors only for some of the components. For Example i do not see Unresolved reference error for TFC_net.dll. All these components are present in Bin folder. Below is the content from group_Client.wxs

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment Id="Frag.Client">
    <ComponentGroup Id="Group.Client">
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.boost_signalsvc140mt1_61.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.boost_regexvc140mt1_61.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.boost_threadvc140mt1_61.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.cximageu.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.oc1210asu.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.og1210asu.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.ov1210asu.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.SystemFolder.AddFlow4.ocx"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.SystemFolder.HFlow.ocx"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.Interop.SHDocVw.dll"/>
    <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.TXXFC_net.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.TFC_net.dll"/>
       <ComponentRef Id="Comp.Bin.ValNet.dll"/>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am newbie to wix and msi. Could some help me in resolving these link errors.

We Build using jam Build tool, We have action rules written in the Jam scripts.

```html
actions MakeMSIFromWIX bind PRODUCTWIXLIB 
{
 $(LIGHT) $(LIGHTOPT) -b $(SUBDIR) -out $(<) $(>) $(PRODUCTWIXLIB)   
}
```

We have used the below light options.
$(LIGHT) will call Light.exe
LIGHTOPT += -nologo -spdb -sice:ICE03 -sice:ICE61 -ext WixUtilExtension.dll;

Comment: How do you build the MSI, from within Visual Studio (Votive addon)? What is "MakeMSIFromWIX", a custom tool?

Comment: I have edited and added the info in my question. Please have a look.